# Performance testing with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I've recorded a test script of web application (extJS). The test logs into application (I used login and password saved in .txt file and CSV Data Set Config element), makes some calculations with external webservice and adds some elements to database. It works fine but...
I'm not sure that all of my users do these things at the same time... Is there any way to configure it? 
E.g 100 users do the same scenario at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the exact number of concurrent users via [Active Threads Over Time Listener](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/)

[image: Active Threads Over Time]

If you're not happy with what you're seeing and expect more concurrent users you can consider 2 options:

1. Increase "Loop Count" on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level as when JMeter thread has finished executing all samplers and doesn't have any more to run and no loops to iterate - it's being shut down.
2. Add [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer). It pauses all the threads until the desired amount is reached and releases them at exactly the same moment so you will be able to test i.e. what happens when 100 users are trying to log in at the same time.